# Web services failure report and news

Tags: web-services, bpel

I am trying to find

1. The report on the general Web service failure rate;
2. Some news regarding the web service failure like （best from more famous news source) http://blog.crowdflower.com/2008/07/amazons-s3-web-service-our-1-cause-of-failure/

If you aware of those, please share it here, thanks.

(this is trying to emphasize to my colleagues on how important to have proper fault handling mechanism for web services)

Comment: 1) I bet this really depends on how certain web services are cut, designed and implemented. What works well for one company may fail for another.
2) How is this related to BPEL?

Comment: I am just looking for some general statistic..as bpel is a composite service which makes use of component service, since component services can fail often, therefore proper fault handling mechanism in composite service is needed.